# Correct location of navigation controller code for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

For customizing the navigation bar in the navigator view, I used `self.navigationController!.navigationBar`
to access it. I did this from the .swift file of the first view controller I had. It works fine but I was wondering if there is a better place to put the code that I am missing? Does anyone ever use separate .swift files for the navigation view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a horrible way to do it. It certainly gets the job done.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish there are a couple ways you could access the navigation bar.

1. For a situation where you need to customize the bar specifically for the view you are in, doing it the way you described is good.

*One note:* You are force-unwrapping `navigationController`. If you decide to do this you just need to make sure that view controller will always live inside a `UINavigationController`.

2. In a situation where you want to customize the look and feel no matter what view you are in you could subclass a `UINavigationController` and in its `viewDidLoad` method do any sort of customization in there. Then instead of creating a navigation controller like this `UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: someViewController)`, you would use your subclass of `UINavigationController` instead. `YourNavigationControllerClass.init(rootViewController: someViewController)`

---

For #2 you would want to create a new class and put the code in that new class `viewDidLoad` method.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great, that was very helpful! One thing I'm still unsure about in case 2: in which .swift file would it be best to define the UINavigationController subclass and create a navigation controller?

Comment: @SarahBoo I updated the answer to address your question. You would create a new swift class that is a subclass of `UINavigationController`.